# How can I create iCal events and download/export event in .ics file in swift. I want file in Files in my iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, events, file-io, icalendar

I tried to create an event from details getting from api response but failed, I want the event created in swift to write in a .ics file and then export to files in my iPhone. I Created text file and added text in it successfully but failed to get added text to .ics file(Code is added)
So my question is how to create an editable .ics file, then how to create an iCal event, and then how to write that event details in .ics file, Then how to export this file in Files in iPhone
Please ignore if some thing crate confusion, My code is here!

```
if let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent("my_iCsFile").appendingPathExtension("ics") {
   let dtstart = "This is strt date"
   let dtend = "this is end date"
   let location = "This is location"
   let summary = "This is summery"
   let outString: String = "dtstart:\(dtstart)\ndtend:\(dtend)\nlocation:\(location)\nsummery:\(summary)"
        do {
            try
               outString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
           } catch {
            print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
           }
      }
```

Any sample of cede, help, link or tutorial will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I waited here, and searched a lot for some solution, iFound the following, I just passed some values like starting/ ending date, name/title and summery and this returnees me the correct formate of text that should be written in .ics file. file saving process is same as mentioned in my Question.
this is the link to solution :

https://github.com/kiliankoe/iCalKit

in question dir is used. dir is actually global var to root directory

```
let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                           in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
```

and in file export function just pass the event detail (don't forget to add iCalKit library in the project, writing and exporting code is here

```
if let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent("my_iCsFile").appendingPathExtension("ics") {
  
   let outString: String  =  String here that generated by iCal event (iCalKit will make sure for us that the string is in iCalEvent format to write in .ics file)
        do {
            try
               outString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
           } catch {
            print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
           }
      }
```